# Simultaneous measurement of non-commuting observables without uncertainty

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurements, observables

A pair of non-commuting Observables $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$ does not have a common set of eigenfunctions, i.e., it can not be measured simultaneously. Let us for the sake of simplicity assume that $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=i\hat{1}$ as for position and momentum observables.

On the other hand, it is well known that using an enlarged Hilbert space, it is possible to define Observables $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ in this enlarged Hilbert space with $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$ so that $\langle \hat{A} \rangle = \langle \hat{X} \rangle$ and $\langle \hat{B} \rangle = \langle \hat{P} \rangle$ (see, e.g., [section 3.3](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.6815v2.pdf)). Since $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute, there exists a common set of eigenfunctions for which $\hat{A} |A B \rangle = A |A B \rangle$ and $\hat{B} |A B \rangle = B |A B \rangle$, respectively. Briefly put, it is possible to define a pair of commuting observables $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$, which can be simultaneously measured in order to infer $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$.

If one assumes that the states in the two Hilbert spaces have to factorize (i.e., that they are separable), then it is possible to derive the uncertainty relation $\Delta \hat{A} \Delta \hat{B} \geq 1$. Thus, a measurement in the enlarged Hilbert space can be performed simultaneously, but at the cost of an additional uncertainty in comparison with the Kennard relation $\Delta \hat{X} \Delta \hat{P} \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

However, according to Robertsons's uncertainty relation, one has $\Delta \hat{A} \Delta \hat{B} \geq \frac{1}{2} |\langle [\hat{A},\hat{B}] \rangle| = 0$, with some kind of minimal uncertainty state $|A B \rangle$. Motivated by this statenment, my question is: **Is it possible to utilize the common eigenfunctions $|A B \rangle$ to perform a joint measurement of non-commuting observables in an enlarged Hilbert space without uncertainty?** If no, why not? If yes, why cant this be exploited for measurements?

Comment: The enlarged Hilbert space is sth. you add for performing the measurement. Thus, it will always be in a product state with the system you want to measure, and $\Delta\hat A\Delta\hat B\ge 1$ will hold -- as you point out yourself, the minimal uncertainty states are entangled states of system + ancilla.

Comment: I agree that the usual approach is to have a product state. But why is it not possible to entangle system + ancilla by means of a unitary transformation so that the joint state is a minimal uncertainty state with $\hat{A}\hat{B} = 0$? Or, put differently, how could one prepare such an optimal measurement state $|AB\rangle$?

Comment: The problem is unitarily invariant. If you use some $U$ to entangle it before, then $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ will be modified accordingly.  It simply does not work out.  Since the uncertainty relation still holds if you use any POVM measurement, adding ancillas in any conceivable way cannot help.

Comment: Again, I agree to your statement. However, what meaning does the eigenfunction $|AB\rangle$ have in this case? It seems to exist, but at the same time seems to be impossible to prepare?

Comment: Precisely, ,the joint eigenfunctions (before the unitary) are entangled states between system and ancilla.  (Rather than $X$ and $P$, think of Pauli $X$ and Pauli $Z$, which you can "make commuting" by measuring $X\otimes X$ and $Z\otimes Z$.  Their joint eigenstates are Bell states.)

Comment: So why cant I exploit this by making the unitary evolution $\hat{1}$ and then projectively measuring said eigenstates? Since they are joint eigenstates of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$, it should be possible to measure thes observables without uncertainty.

Comment: I suggest you try working this out. (I.e., with writing formulas and all that.) Then you should learn where this fails.

Comment: I tried and failed. Thats why I asked here.

Comment: The way in which you fail should give you some intuition on *why* it cannot work.  The way your question is phrased now it seems un-answerable -- I don't have the impression you would be happy with a proof that the uncertainty cannot be violated by a general (i.e., POVM) measurement, which would include ancillas.

Comment: The problem is: all textboox/paper explanations start from a system + ancilla approach leading to the above-mentioned uncertainty relation with right-hand side $1$. But _in principle_ there should be joint eigenstates $|AB\rangle$ of the observables $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ in the enlarged Hilbert space, since $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$. So my question can be phrased as: why is it not possible to prepare a system + ancilla in $|AB\rangle$ to make an optimal measurement? I have no idea how to approach this problem in a good way and have never seen anyone stating anything about this particular task.

Comment: Any system + ancilla measurement can be rephrased as a POVM measurement.  I'm sure you can find derivations of the uncertainty relation with POVMs rather than projective measurements.  But I'm afraid you don't want an impossibility proof, but you want to understand *where exactly* your intuition fails.  Since we can't look into your mind, this is tricky, so I think the best way would be if you try again and again until you build intuition about *why* it fails.

Comment: "Any system + ancilla measurement can be rephrased as a POVM measurement" -- im not sure if this is true or at least I have not seen this yet. I only know Neumark's theorem stating the converse, i.e., that any POVM can be realized by a system + ancilla approach. Nevertheless, your comments were helpful and I still hope that you might write a full answer.

Comment: This is true, and is a standard result which should be in any textbook.  If you ask it as a separate question, I'll be happy to explain the proof in an answer.